# Create a Cookie in Email Campaign

Tags: javascript, email, cookies

I have a blog that requires users to login to view the content. But my page checks for a cookie, if cookie exists then it shows the content (to avoid users having to login repeatedly).

I want to send out an email to my subscribers with links to new posts. Is it possible for me to create a cookie when they open the email or click the link and then recognize that cookie on my website to prevent the requirement of them needing to login?

Comment: That is probably a bad idea (think what happens if the user forwards the email?) but usually that's done by appending a token to the url (e.g. `http://example.com/blog-post&autologin=[random token here]`) and having the server log the user in when it recognizes the token.

Comment: The content is not intended to be super secure. Just a way to get more users to opt-in so the forwarding case is not a major concern for us.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Most email clients capable of rendering HTML will not, by default, load any remote content or run scripts. And using a JavaScript cookie for authentication is inherently insecure anyway.

Give the a link to click on in the email with a one-time-password and set a http-only, secure cookie from the page the URL links to.

Comment: The content is not intended to be super secure. Just a way to get more users to opt-in so the forwarding case is not a major concern for us.